# Imread function of opencv can't open my images, what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: c++, opencv, path

as the title suggest i have problems with opencv and in particulare with imread function. This is the simple program I'm trying to run

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui.hpp>


using namespace cv;

int main(){
    std::string path = "Images/NewYork.jpg";
Mat img = imread(path);
imshow("image", img);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

}

My CMakeLists looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(Convolution)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
include_directories( 
${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable(Convolution main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Convolution 
${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

The message error that I'm getting is:
[ WARN:0@0.001] global /opt/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp (244) findDecoder imread_('Images/NewYork.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'

what():  OpenCV(4.6.0-dev) /opt/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:969: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

I know that the second error is due to the fact that the Mat object is empty and that's becuase my imread function does'nt work. I already checked if my path is correct, i saved my image in different directories, i checked the spelling, i checked evertyhing and i can't make it work. Please help.

Comment: The message means what it says, The file path is wrong. Probably you are mistaken in what you think the current working directory is. To test this you could try an absolute path instead of a relative one.

Comment: try with passing specific image format "imread(image_path, IMREAD_COLOR);". also try with some drifrent image file format and file extensions. if not work check your file permissions, and run application with admin privilege.

Answer (score 2):

You should always check whether your `cv2.imread()` succeeded or not by seeing if it returns `NULL` data.

You may be running inside an IDE, or from a different directory, so consider using [getcwd()](https://linuxhint.com/getcwd-function-c/) and printing the result so you know where the relative path to your `Images` directory starts.

Answer (score 0):

You path is still wrong most likely. Try with the absolute path first, then check what your working directory of the process actually is (when debugging, thats probably the same as your main.cpp).

If you get completely stuck on that, try writing an image for a change (create a cvMat and use imwrite). Then see where it turns up.

If you want to use relative paths (which makes a lot of sense) i'd recommend a `"./Images/NewYork.jpg"` syntax to make that clearer.

Comment: the working directory of the **process** of your program. the *compiler* has nothing to do with any of that.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put full path instaed of shortened path.

ex) "D://images//example.jpg"

Comment: Double forward slashes are unnecessary.

Comment: not just that, they're probably also an error, which depends on whether anything specifically implements tolerance to this malformed path string.